# Read an invalid cookie with Java (jsp)?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a cookie that is formatted like `partA:partB`. The colon is not escaped in any fashion. I need to read this cookie in a JSP script, and `request.getCookies()` is only returning `partA`. I can't change the cookie because it is used in multiple applications, and fixing the cookie would break production code. Any ideas how I can read the full value of this cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read the [Cookie header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) directly using the [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought of that.